# Determining the 10 highest values of two levels in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am very new to R and have recently been given a project to determine the top 10 most popular names for each sex in a data frame.
I have 3 columns of information which I have labeled 'name' 'gender' and 'amount'. I think the biggest problem I am facing is trying to group all of the males together and then all of the females together in the 'gender' column. And then my next question would be to find the top 10 values for each. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it your homework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using many ways in `R`.

#### base R:

In `base R`, there are some regular grouping and extracting techniques  you could use like `ave`, `by`, or perhaps `aggregate` etc. In the methods shown below, I first ordered the data by columns `sex` and `amount` with `amount` in descending order (note the `-` sign). Then, I use `ave` to get a logical index of the first 10 observations.

```
dat1 <- dat[order(dat$sex, -dat$amount),]
indx <- with(dat1, ave(seq_along(amount), sex, FUN=seq_along) %in% 1:10)
indx
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [49] FALSE FALSE

dat1[indx,]
```

Alternatively, we can also get the first `10` rows by using a combination of `head`, `by` functions

```
 do.call(rbind, by(dat1, list(dat1$sex), FUN=head,10))
```

To learn more about these functions, do `?<function>` in the R-console, e.g., `?ave` to learn about the function and it's usage.

---

You can also use additional packages to accomplish the task. If your dataset is really big. I would suggest doing this by `dplyr` or `data.table` as it is efficient in handling big datasets.

#### dplyr:

In the code below, I am using the latest version of `dplyr` i.e., `dplyr 0.3`. You can get it from the [github project page of dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

The operations in `dplyr` uses the chain `%>%` for connecting different operations. In the code below, we are first grouping the `dat` by `sex`, then order the `amount` variable descendingly, and in the last step use `slice` to get the first 10 rows of each `sex`.  In `dplyr 0.2` you can use `dO(head(., 10)` instead.

```
dat %>% 
    group_by(sex) %>% 
    arrange(desc(amount)) %>%
     slice(1:10) #do(head(., 10) #in `dplyr 0.2`
```

which gives the result

```
 #     name sex amount
 #1     N   F     98
 #2     R   F     97
 #3     Q   F     97
 #4     T   F     95
 #5     S   F     91
 #6     A   F     91
 #7     Y   F     89
 #8     Z   F     87
 #9     T   F     85
 #10    Y   F     85
 #11    X   M     98
 #12    Q   M     97
 #13    K   M     96
 #14    O   M     90
 #15    A   M     90
 #16    X   M     86
 #17    D   M     84
 #18    V   M     84
 #19    C   M     83
 #20    X   M     78
```

---

#### data.table:

In terms of speed, [in documented cases](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Benchmarks-%3A-Grouping), `data.table` is highly efficient. Here also, the idea is to sort data by `amount` column in descending order (note the `-`), *group by* sex on the ordered data, and for each group subset the first 10 rows using `.SD` which means `Subset of Data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[order(-amount), .SD[1:10], by=sex] ## or head(.SD, 10L)
```

**Note:** If you are working with `data.frame`, you can convert to `data.table` using

```
DT <- as.data.table(dat)
```

Alternatively, you can also do `setDT` to convert to `data.table`. It converts the `data.frame` to `data.table` *by reference* (without any additonal copy/memory usage), as shown above.

#### data:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(name=sample(LETTERS, 50, replace=TRUE),
      sex=sample(c("M", "F"), 50, replace=TRUE), amount=sample(40:100, 50, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: @pumpkintea  Your code is different from any of the ones that I showed here. It is not clear when you say that my suggestions are not working?  You can copy and paste the code in your post and update it along with an example dataset using `dput` as I showed here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far !
I can't seem to get any of your suggestions working with my code. 

Here is what I had tried so far 

apply(as.matrix(d),2,function(x) 
  (as.matrix(d[,1],d[,2],d[,3])[order(d[,3],decreasing=TRUE)[1:10]])
)
This retruns the top 10 name values in descending order but without showing the 'sex'or the 'amount'.

Comment: @pumpkintea  I didn't show any `apply(as.matrix(2))..` here

Comment: I tried using 

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(d, key='sex'); 
DT[order(-amount), .SD[1:10], by=sex]

But got the error
Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called ‘data.table’
> DT <- data.table(d, key='sex'); 
Error: could not find function "data.table"
> DT[order(-amount), .SD[1:10], by=sex]
Error: object 'DT' not found

Comment: @pumpkintea You have to install the package `install.packages('data.table')` and then load the package `library(data.table)` before you perform any operations.  This is relevant to all additional packages except the `base R`.

Comment: I just tried your base R approach and it worked like a charm. You're a life saver thank you soo much ! I'm sorry for being confusing but your patience and help really means so much !!